# i am getting an error when running django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, file, error-handling

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x038C1C48>
```

this is what i get when trying to run an app that was created earlier on a different machine, when i create a new project it runs just fine but everytime i try to run the app that had been created before it throws the error listed here in above, please assist. this is the whole CMD dump:

```
C:\Users\Gavina\Desktop\kesh\lawcases>python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gavina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\logging\config.py", line 562, in configure
    handler = self.configure_handler(handlers[name])
  File "C:\Users\Gavina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\logging\config.py", line 735, in configure_handler
    result = factory(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gavina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1092, in __init__
    StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
  File "C:\Users\Gavina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1121, in _open
    return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\opt\\django-cases\\logs\\debug.log'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Gavina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Gavina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Gavina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "C:\Users\Gavina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.3-py3.7.egg\django\utils\log.py", line 76, in configure_logging
    logging_config_func(logging_settings)
  File "C:\Users\Gavina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\logging\config.py", line 799, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "C:\Users\Gavina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\logging\config.py", line 570, in configure
    '%r' % name) from e
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file'
```

Thank you for your assistance

Comment: Have you tried to create `C:\\opt\\django-cases\\logs\\debug.log`?

Comment: you probably just changed the `LOGGING` settings to log to file. Make sure the `debug.log` file actually exists at the location mentioned in the error.